# Why are my process.env variables undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tedious

even though I am using:
require('dotenv').config() at the top of my modules, my process.env variables (set in my .env file) are undefined.

This, despite the fact that my IDE clearly is seeing them as defined bc it autofills the variable names as I type them out.

Very strange.  Any thoughts?

```html
require('dotenv').config();


let config = {
  userName: process.env.userName,
  password: process.env.password,
  server: process.env.server
}
```

here's my .env file:

```
    userName='myNmae'
    password='myPassword'
    server='myServer.com'
    PORT=3001
```

Comment: try `require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'})` or sending whatever the absolute path the to file is

Comment: How do you run that code?

Comment: Is your `.env` file in the **root** directory of your project? If not, move it or define a path as @Asthmatic comment has shown.

Comment: Thanks folks.  @Asthmatic - I will try that.

Comment: Thanks folks.  
Asthmatic - I will try that.
zerkms - I only showed a tidbit of my code (the parts pertinent to dotenv)
Xorifelse - Yes, it's in the root.  I've built a number of node applications in the last 9 months and have not had this happen before. (If I did I don't remember what the issue was.)

Answer (score 0):

For me they were undefined for 2 reasons:

- My variables did not have `VUE_APP_` prefixed to them, for Vue that seems to be necessary.
- I had inserted the variables into my .env file AFTER starting the server and had not restarted it yet.

Hope this helps some lost soul.